# Integral $\int_0^\pi \cos (( n-m) x )\frac{\sin^2 (nmx)}{\sin(nx)\sin(mx)} \rm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> I am trying to calculate the value of the integral
> $$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \cos \left(( n-m) x \right) \frac{\sin^2 (nmx)}{\sin(nx)\sin(mx)} \textrm{d}x$$ with $n, m$ integers greater than $1$.

When I give particular values ​​of $n$ and $m$, wolfram alpha uses magic simplifications and finds the value of the integral. For example if $n=7$ and $m=3$ the integral is reduced to $${\int} (\cos\left(36x\right)+\cos\left(30x\right)+\cos\left(28x\right)+\cos\left(24x\right)+2\cos\left(22x\right)+\cos\left(18x\right)+2\cos\left(16x\right)+$$$$\cos\left(14x\right)+\cos\left(12x\right)+2\cos\left(10x\right)+2\cos\left(8x\right)+\cos\left(6x\right)+2\cos\left(4x\right)+2\cos\left(2x\right)+1)\mathrm{d}x $$

It also gives a [simplified form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+cos(m*x-n*x)+sin(m*n*x)%5E2%2F(sin(m*x)*sin(n*x))), but I do not know how to exploit it.

Comment: After several tries with wolfram,
Can someone give me an example of a couple (n, m) that returns a value of the integral different from the gcd (n, m)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this is an elementary solution.

Via the formula
\begin{equation*}
 a^p-b^p = (a-b)\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}a^{p-1-k}b^{k}
\end{equation*}
and Euler's formula we get
\begin{gather*}
 \sin^2(nmx) = \left(\dfrac{e^{inmx}-e^{-inmx}}{2i}\right)^{2} =\dfrac{\left(e^{inx}\right)^{m}-\left(e^{-inx}\right)^{m}}{2i}\cdot \dfrac{\left(e^{imx}\right)^{n}-\left(e^{-imx}\right)^{n}}{2i}=\\[2ex]
 \dfrac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{2i}\dfrac{e^{imx}-e^{-imx}}{2i}\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}e^{inx(m-1-k)}e^{-inxk}\cdot \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}e^{imx(n-1-j)}e^{-imxj}=\\[2ex]
 \sin(nx)\sin(mx)\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}e^{ix(2nm-n-m-2kn-2jm)}
\end{gather*}
Thus
\begin{gather*}
 \cos((n-m)x)\dfrac{\sin^2(nmx)}{\sin(nx)\sin(mx)}=\\[2ex]\dfrac{e^{i(n-m)x}+e^{-i(n-m)x}}{2}\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}e^{ix(2nm-n-m-2kn-2jm)}=\\[2ex]
 \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}e^{ix(2nm-2m-2kn-2jm)}+ \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}e^{ix(2nm-2n-2kn-2jm)}.\tag{1}
\end{gather*}
However,
\begin{equation*}
 \dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{i2px}\, \mathrm{d}x = \begin{cases}
 0\text{ if } p\neq 0 \text{ and integer },\\
 1 \text{ if } p=0.
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Now we integrate the two double sums in(1). By symmetry the two integrals will have the same value.
The integral
\begin{equation*}
  \dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{ix(2nm-2m-2kn-2jm)}\, \mathrm{d}x = 1
\end{equation*}
if and only if
\begin{gather*}
nm-m-kn-jm=0 \tag{2}
\end{gather*}
which is a linear diophantine equaion.

Put $n= pd, m=qd$ where $d=\rm{gcd}(n,m)$. Then we can write (2) as
\begin{equation*}
 kp+jq=pqd-q.
\end{equation*}
All solutions are
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
 k=qd-rq\\
 j=-1+rp
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
where $r$ is an integer. But $0 \le k \le m-1$ and $0\le j \le n-1$. Thus
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
 0\le qd-rq \le qd-1\\
 0 \le -1+rp \le pd -1
 \end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow 
 \begin{cases}
 1\le rq \text{ and } r\le d\\
 1 \le rp \text{ and } r\le d.
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Consequently we find $d$ solutions to (2).
If we integrate (1) we get 
\begin{equation*}
 \dfrac{1}{2}d+\dfrac{1}{2}d = \rm{gcd(n,m).}
\end{equation*}

Comment: I like this way  Thank you

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: nice work and +1

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

The value of the integral equals $\gcd (m,n)$ as stated in this [article](https://lipn.univ-paris13.fr/%7Esedjelmaci/coMI2.pdf) and the solution is not elemantary.

**article citation:** *Sedjelmaci, Sidi Mohamed*, [**Some related functions to integer GCD and coprimality**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.endm.2011.05.024), Bonomo, Flavia (ed.) et al., LAGOS’11 — VI Latin-American algorithms, graphs, and optimization symposium. Extended abstracts from the symposium, Bariloche, Argentina, March 28—April 1, 2011. Amsterdam: Elsevier. Electronic Notes in Discrete Mathematics 37, 135-140 (2011). [ZBL1268.11162](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1268.11162).

Comment: The question was asked by a research professor Thank you for this article

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: this result is very interesting simply because it extends the definition of the GCD to non-integral values, for example $$\gcd \left( \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \right)=\frac{1}{\pi }$$

Comment: Perhaps the professor would hope that we can find a direct way to calculate the integral

Comment: he hopes to much!!!!